# How do I Detect page breaks with PHP

Tags: php, page-break

Is there a way to detect page breaks with php?
I generate a report with PHP and I use page breaks for different paragraphes.
I need to keep a header in every page.
Is there a way to do it?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by page break ?

Comment: Page breaks? There is no such thing as page breaks in PHP. Are you referring to printing?

Comment: page-break in what? HTML, PDF or what medium are you talking about?

Comment: @Ali, I know the issue you are trying to resolve.  It's not simple, unfortunately.  PHP is "unaware" of the size/layout of the pages it is producing in your report.  You have to think about it differently when you generate a report via PHP.  Keeping a header in every page will be challenging.  You basically need to code "logic" into your php script to "guess" where a page SHOULD break, and use the html answer below to insert an element that CAUSES a page break.  And, because different people will have different results, you need to be conservative with how often you add those breaks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HTML (only using CSS):**

`<hr style="page-break-after:always; visibility: hidden">`

**PDF:**

use the HTML above and use `wkhtmltopdf` to convert to PDF. Other converters might work, yet this one is the best.

**TEXT/CONSOLE(CLI):**

`chr(0xC)`, aka `"\f"`.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you can grep for \f as seen in the Wiki: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_break

if you explode on \f like so:

```
explode('\f', $string);
```

It should form an array of pages.

Beaware this does not always work, there are curcumstances where you think there is a page break but actually your viewing software is breaking the page for you.